# Release version of application cannot make API Calls?

Tags: flutter, dart, google-play

I have completed an application that works fine in development env, both on android emulator and android phone.

I created a keystore, added INTERNET_PERMISSION to my manifest and followed the guide to release pretty much perfectly.

However, when I download the release app from the play store (it is in internal testing), the login API (and presumably the other APIs) do not work and infinitely load.

What did I miss?

The IOS Application is working perfectly in Testflight.

Comment: are you using firebase ?

Answer (score 0):

**Assuming that you are using firebase.**

After deployment to playstore.

**Go to Play Console → Open App → Setup (Left panel) → App Integrity**

you should be able to see something like this.

[image]

add the **SHA-1** and **SHA-256** fingerprint to the firebase project in firebase console and it should work after that.

**Open Firebase Console → Open Project → Project Settings → General,** scroll to very last and add these certificates.

**UPDATE:**
You need to get the new `google-services.json` from firebase, add it to your app, make new build and re-deploy to playstore with a new version for this to work.

Comment: Did not work. I am using FCM for notifications, but I am still having the same error after adding the keys to the app in firebase.

Comment: I did a mistake by mentioning that you dont need to re-deploy. I checked and the 
`google-services.json` is updated after making changes to the certificates on firebase. 
updated the answer @TamimChowdhury

Comment: It still doesn't work - I updated the keys and updated google-services.
Then I built the appbundle again and rolled out the new release.
Upon further debugging, I found this is the issue:

2021-02-14 23:34:37.631 28553-28597/? E/flutter: [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(177)] Unhandled Exception: MissingPluginException(No implementation found for method getToken on channel plugins.flutter.io/firebase_messaging)

Comment: @TamimChowdhury https://github.com/FirebaseExtended/flutterfire/issues/2829#issuecomment-652900664